# How to have Spring aspect support for repeatable annotation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations, aop

I have created a java 17 repeatable annotation and want to create an aspect **around** the method containing the annotation is invoked. This seems to work when method is annotated once but fails to invoke when I have repeatable annotation. I am using aspectjrt version 1.9.7. Am I doing something wrong or aspect doesn't support repeatable annotations? Any workaround for the same?

Annotation class ->

```
@Repeatable(Schedules.class)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Schedule {
  String dayOfMonth() default "first";
  String dayOfWeek() default "Mon";
  int hour() default 12;
}
```

The repeatable class ->

```
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Schedules {
    Schedule[] value();
}
```

The aspect class ->

```
@Aspect
@Component
@Slf4j
public class Aspect {

    @Around("@annotation(Schedule)")
    public Object trace(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

        MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
        Method method = signature.getMethod();

        Schedule filters = method.getAnnotation(Schedule.class);
        //Business Logic
        return joinPoint.proceed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be  `@annotation(package.to.Schedule)` ? Also could you please confirm the aspect fails to advise when just the `@Repeatable` annotation is changed and the rest of the code remains the same ? If this is pseudo code , could you please shre an actcual [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually is not an AOP problem, but you need to understand how repeatable annotations work in Java: If the annotation appears multiple times on the annotated element, it is not represented as a single annotation anymore but as an array of annotations in the `value()` of the annotation type mentioned in `@Repeatable`, i.e. in your case `@Schedules` (plural "s"!).

For your aspect, it means that you need two pointcuts, one for the single-annotation case and one for the multi-annotation one. I am suggesting to factor out the common advice code into a helper method of the aspect which always takes an array of the repeatable annotations, then just pass the value of the wrapper annotation on in one case and a one-element array in the other case.

Feel free to ask follow-up questions, if anything is unclear. But it should be straightforward, almost trivial.

Resources:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/repeating.html
- https://dzone.com/articles/repeatable-annotations-in-java-8-1

P.S.: You should learn about how to bind annotations to advice method parameters:

```java
@Around("@annotation(schedule)")
public Object traceSingle(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, Schedule schedule) throws Throwable

// ...

@Around("@annotation(schedules)")
public Object traceMultiple(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, Schedules schedules) throws Throwable
```

Comment: Yes. Thank you, I had to introduce a new advice method with @Around("@annotation(schedules)").